# Two simultaneous events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a JS code using on this page http://200tr.ru/app/admin/
When I press the cross sign, 2 events occur (blur and click), but only blur-code runs. I need contra, click-on-cross code. 
How can I do this?

---

```
$(function(){clickOnLink();});
    function clickOnLink(){
        $("span.link").on({
            click: function(){
        var linkId = $(this).text().replace(/\D+/g,"");
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var idNum = $(this).attr("id").replace(/\D+/g,"");
        var idType = "link_"+$(this).attr("id").replace(/\d+/g,"");
        var result = "<span class='link'>Переход на link</span> <input     type='text' id='"+id+"' value='"+linkId+"'> <span><span class='plus'>+</span><span    class='cross'>✘</span></span>";
        $(this).replaceWith(function(index, oldHTML){
        return result;
        });
        $("input").focus();
        clickOnCross();
        blurOnInput();
        }
    });
};
function clickOnCross(){
$("span.cross").on({
    click: function(){
        $(this).remove();
     }
});
};
function blurOnInput(){
$("input").on({
    blur: function(){
        $(this).prev().remove();
        $(this).next().remove();
        var idName = $(this).attr("id");
        var idNum = $(this).attr("id").replace(/\D+/g,"");
        var idType = "link_"+$(this).attr("id").replace(/\d+/g,"");
        $(this).replaceWith(function(index, newHTML){
        var linkId = $(this).val();
        var linkIdDb = "link"+$(this).val();
        $.get("handlers/send_link.php", { 
            id: idNum, 
            ans: idType,
            linkid: linkIdDb }
        );
        var result = "<span class='link' id='"+idName+"'>Переход на link"+linkId+". <a href='#link"+linkId+"'>⇗</a></span>";
        return result;
        });       
        clickOnLink();
    }
});
};
```

Comment: You should format your code, I'd edit it but it's a pain in an iPhone

Answer (score 0):

You remove the cross on the `blur` event which triggers on `mousedown`, way before a `click` event is invoked, and when you expect your `click` event to be triggered, there is no `cross` element anymore in `DOM`.

If you would like to bind something on the `click` event of your cross sign, don't remove it from `DOM` on the `blur` event of your `input` field.